# How can I customize a SharePoint Page with no left-side navigation and Search on top?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, navigation, custom-masterpage, responsive-template

I need to create the layout bellow in SharePoint Online.

Please notice this requirements:

1. There should be no left side navigation.
2. The Search functionality should be on the top right corner.
3. The page should be responsive so that, in small screens, web parts that are side-by-side should get on top of each other instead.

[image]

Comment: The top banner should be 100% of the screen and the content bellow should be centralized

Comment: I was able to use responsive layout by adding sections. It works great. My biggest issues are items 1 and 2.

Comment: Search is moving to the suitenav, something you won't be able to manipulate. No left side navigation can be done on Communication sites (they're configured this way OOTB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There should be no left left side navigation.
   ***= You can change it by, clicking on gear, change the look then at the bottom you see the classic change the look option, click it, you will be redirected to the classic page on changing the looks option, click the current layout, then at the left side, you can see a dropdown option for site layout, change the 'Seatle' to 'Oslo' then save it, see the update in the site.***

   2. The Search functionality should be on the top right corner.
      = ***Im not sure if this is doable in modern, you can create a custom webpart dedicated for this piece via [spfx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part) webpart but it would be a bit overkill***
   3. The page should be responsive so that, in small screens, web parts that are side-by-side should get on top of each other instead.
      ***= Modern sharepoint will do this for you. You can also test it out in their SharePoint App, its in the apps store.***

Let me know if the concept helps, happy learning!

Comment: Thanks your tip for number one actually helped me solving number 2 as well. I have now a classic page with no left-side navigation and search in the top right corner.

Comment: My challenge now is how to deploy my SPFx web parts to a classic page. I am trying to use PnP but it is not working. I've created a new post for that: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/279500/pnpwebparttowebpartpage-error-file-not-found