# PnPWebPartToWebPartPage error: File not found

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, pnp-powershell, classic-experience

I am trying to install a SPFx Web Part in a Classic SharePoint Online Page using PnP.

First I connect to the tenant

```
Connect-PnPOnline –Url https://company.sharepoint.com/ –Credentials (Get-Credential)
```

Then I run this command

```
Add-PnPWebPartToWebPartPage -ServerRelativePageUrl "/sites/Company/Pages/CompanyPage.aspx" -Xml "C:\QLWebPart.xml" -ZoneId "Custom Zone" -ZoneIndex 0
```

and I get this error:

> Add-PnPWebPartToWebPartPage : File Not Found. At line:1 char:1
>   + Add-PnPWebPartToWebPartPage -ServerRelativePageUrl "/sites/Company ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Add-PnPWebPartToWebPartPage], ServerException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.WebParts.AddWebPartToWebPartPage

Which makes no sense because the file exists.
I've tried renaming to .xml as well but nothing

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The module documentation provides two clear examples for adding a web part to a web part page in a specified zone. 
You can use the *-Path* option that defines **a path to a web part file on the file system**:

```
Add-PnPWebPartToWebPartPage -ServerRelativePageUrl "/sites/demo/sitepages/home.aspx" -Path "c:\myfiles\listview.webpart" -ZoneId "Header" -ZoneIndex 1
```

or *-XML* option that defines **a string containing the XML for the web part**:

```
Add-PnPWebPartToWebPartPage -ServerRelativePageUrl "/sites/demo/sitepages/home.aspx" -XML $webpart -ZoneId "Header" -ZoneIndex 1
```

You can find more details [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnpwebparttowebpartpage?view=sharepoint-ps).